# how to login with Facebook using webview

Tags: android, facebook, redirect

Whenever i click the button "login with facebook" in any android app, it redirects me to facebook app. When the Facebook app is not installed, the webview for facebook login pops up.
How to make the webview window appear without redirecting to facebook app?